# Angular 2: ngIf template parsing error

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

I have a dynamic template and I'm getting an error that states:

```
Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.
```

Here is my template:

```
<ion-col>
    <button *ngIf=!editMode" class="warning-gradient" (click)="toggleEdit()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Update</button>
    <button *ngIf="editMode" class="warning-success" (click)="submitForm()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Update</button>
</ion-col>
```

... am I supposed to do something differently?

Comment: `*ngIf="!editMode"` you're missing the opening `"` on the first button

Comment: @jmw5598 why don't you add that as an answer? Seems to be the solution to the OP

Comment: Oh god... I was staring at that for so long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the opening `"` for the `*ngIf` attribute on the first `<button>`

```
<ion-col>
    <button *ngIf="!editMode" class="warning-gradient" (click)="toggleEdit()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Update</button>
    <button *ngIf="editMode" class="warning-success" (click)="submitForm()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Update</button>
</ion-col>
```